# Append Data To A Column When Column Is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using VB.net I have a button click that updates a SQL Server db table.  The following code works fine except if ColumnOne is NULL:

```
Dim conn As Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection = New  Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("XXXX").ConnectionString)
Dim cmd As Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
cmd = New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("UPDATE MyTable SET ColumnOne = ColumnOne + 'Milk and Cookies'",conn)
cmd.Connection.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd.Connection.Close()
```

When the column is NULL it is not updated.  How can I change the above statement to add "Milk and Cookies" to the column when it is NULL but append to the existing value when it is not NULL.

Comment: Why did you tag this `vb.net`? It looks like it has nothing to do with .NET at all...

Comment: It would really help if you used tags that are actually applicable to your question. This has nothing to do with VB.Net; it's strictly an SQL question, and the answer would be much easier if you used a tag that indicated what database engine (DBMS) you're using because syntax varies. Using the proper tags helps you get answers more quickly, because the question gets the attention of people who are familiar with that topic. It also properly classifies your question in search results for future users of this site. Please [edit] to correct those issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server, You can use COALESCE, which will return the column value if it has any or the specified value if it is NULL. In this case, you want to append to either the column content (if there is content) or to an empty string if the column is NULL.

```
UPDATE 
  MyTable 
SET 
  ColumnOne = COALESCE(ColumnOne, '') + 'Milk and Cookies'
```

If you're using MS Access, you can use IIF() and ISNULL() instead. ISNULL returns True if the value is NULL, False if it isn't, and IIF uses the first option for a True option and the second for False. So you want to use an empty string if ISNULL returns True, and the column value if it returns False (the column is not NULL). Combining the two gives you something like the following:

```
UPDATE 
  MyTable 
SET 
  ColumnOne = IIF(ISNULL(ColumnOne, '', ColumnOne)) + 'Milk and Cookies'
```